# Excel VBA Add New Line Script Not Adding Row Based On Where The Button Is Been Pressed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel spread sheet where I have added a button on a row which I wanted to click, take a copy of that row and then duplicate underneath.

For some reason it does not seem to be selecting the row where I click the button but where ever the cursor is meaning the wrong line is copied.

Is there any way I can change the below to make the active cell where ever the button has just been pressed ?

```
Sub InsertRows()
Dim x As Integer
  x = Application.InputBox("Number of Rows", "Number of Rows", Type:=1)
  If x = False Then Exit Sub
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(x - 1, 0)).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Many thanks in advance

Terran

EDIT

My final solution with Thomas' help.

The slight difference is that this allows the button its self to also be copied as well as the row.

```
Sub InsertRows()


    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    x = Application.InputBox("Number of Rows", "Number of Rows", Type:=1)
    iRow = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row
    If x = False Then Exit Sub

    For i = 0 To (x - 1)


    'Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(x - 1, 0)).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown


    Range("A" & iRow).EntireRow.Copy
    Range("A" & iRow + 1 + i).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown

    Next i
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: What type of button? Forms or ActiveX?

Comment: Hi - its a Forms button. Thanks

Comment: Clicking the button doesn't change the ActiveCell. You can get which button was pressed by looking at Application.Caller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to get the row of the button you have just clicked:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row
```

I don't really understand what you are trying to do with your msgbox collecting an offset. So here's the code to do excatly what you asked, ie copy the row where the button is, on the row right underneath:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim iRow As Integer
    iRow = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row
    Range("A" & iRow).EntireRow.Copy
    Range("A" & iRow + 1).PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

---

EDIT: 
If you want to copy it several times just do this :

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    x = Application.InputBox("Number of Rows", "Number of Rows", Type:=1)
    iRow = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row

    For i = 0 To (x - 1)

        Range("A" & iRow).EntireRow.Copy
        Range("A" & iRow + 1 + i).PasteSpecial

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi - so I've tried to pull your suggestion in to my code but I seem to be having a seniuor moment. The following does seem to work but does not copy any thing in the end. I needed in effect to select the row I want to copy and copy x amount of times based on user in put below. So while your code @Thomas G does work it only allows one row at a time.

Comment: Sub InsertRows()


Dim x As Integer
Dim iRow As Integer

  x = Application.InputBox("Number of Rows", "Number of Rows", Type:=1)
  If x = False Then Exit Sub
    
    iRow = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row
    
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(x - 1, iRow)).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
End Sub

Comment: @TerranBrown See my adapted answer. It wasnt that hard, was it?

Comment: Hi Thomas - your right... off to give my self a beating :) Thanks for your help. Terran